# Convert function to string and back in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
// FYI same thing happens when using a full syntax
const a = () => {
  return "hello world"
}
const aString = a.toString()
const b = new Function(aString)
console.log(b());  // undefined
```

So `b` is a closure of `a` and I could not find an option to prevent the wrapping. Anyone knows how to get back the function without a closure?

Comment: `(() => { return "hello world"; }).toString()` is `"() => { return \"hello world\"; }"`. `new Function` creates a function with the given body, i.e. `(function(){ () => { return "hello world"; } })`. What you’re looking for is `eval`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon unfortunately CSP prevents eval code from running and that's beyond my control

Comment: Whatever prevents `eval` should also prevent `new Function`, then. If `new Function` “works”, then the obvious alternative would be ``new Function(`return ${aString};`)()``.

Comment: `eval()` works in trincot's answer.

Comment: I hope this question is just for curiosity’s sake. If not, what is the actual problem that you think requires `new Function` to solve? There is definitely a better way.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Injecting scripts into a headless browser window. Automations, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Function` expects a *function body* as argument, as stated on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function#parameters):

> A string containing the JavaScript statements comprising the function definition.

The parameters of the function are not included: they can be passed as separate arguments.

There are at least two ways to make this work:

1. You could use `eval` (but in your edit to the question you write this is not possible for your case -- see alternative):

```js
const a = () => {
  return "hello world"
}
const aString = a.toString()
const b = eval(aString)
console.log(b());  // "hello world"
```

Disclaimer: when the stringified function is not fully under your control, it has similar code injection dangers as `new Function`

2. To only use `new Function`, add `return` and execute it -- this unwraps the wrapper:

```js
const a = () => {
  return "hello world"
}
const aString = a.toString()
const b = new Function("return " + aString)();
console.log(b());  // "hello world"
```